# Why when I click next button the form doesn't go to the next page asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

It's supposed to validate and then go to the next view. However, it skips validation entirely and instead reloads the page. I think the issue is with the button itself on the view, I have also tried changing the anchor tag to a submit button, but that just brings me back to the index page. Any help would be appreciated.

My Controller

```
namespace Trip_Log.Controllers
{
    public class TripController : Controller
    {
        private TripLogContext context { get; set; }
        public TripController(TripLogContext ctx) => context = ctx;

        public RedirectToActionResult Cancel()
        {
            TempData.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult Add(string id = "")
        {
            var vm = new TripViewModel();

            if (id == "page2")
            {
                var accomodation = TempData[nameof(Trip.Accommodation)]?.ToString();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accomodation))
                {
                    vm.PageNumber = 3;
                    var destination = TempData[nameof(Trip.Destination)].ToString();
                    vm.Trip = new Trip { Destination = destination };
                    return View("Add3", vm);
                }
                else
                {
                    vm.PageNumber = 2;
                    vm.Trip = new Trip { Accommodation = accomodation };
                    TempData.Keep(nameof(Trip.Accommodation));
                    return View("Add2", vm);
                }

            }
            else if (id == "page3")
            {
                vm.PageNumber = 3;
                vm.Trip = new Trip { Destination = TempData.Peek(nameof(Trip.Destination)).ToString() };
                return View("Add3", vm);
            }
            else
            {
                vm.PageNumber = 1;
                return View("Add1", vm);
            }
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(TripViewModel vm)
        {
            if(vm.PageNumber == 1)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    TempData[nameof(Trip.Destination)] = vm.Trip.Destination;
                    TempData[nameof(Trip.Accommodation)] = vm.Trip.Accommodation;
                    TempData[nameof(Trip.StartDate)] = vm.Trip.StartDate;
                    TempData[nameof(Trip.EndDate)] = vm.Trip.EndDate;
                    return RedirectToAction("Add", new { id = "page2" });
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Add1", vm);
                }
                
            }
            else if(vm.PageNumber == 2)
            {
                TempData[nameof(Trip.AccommodationPhone)] = vm.Trip.AccommodationPhone;
                TempData[nameof(Trip.AccommodationEmail)] = vm.Trip.AccommodationEmail;
                return RedirectToAction("Add", new { id = "page3" });
            }
            else if(vm.PageNumber == 3)
            {
                vm.Trip.Destination = TempData[nameof(Trip.Destination)].ToString();
                vm.Trip.Accommodation = TempData[nameof(Trip.Accommodation)].ToString();
                vm.Trip.StartDate = (DateTime)TempData[nameof(Trip.StartDate)];
                vm.Trip.EndDate = (DateTime)TempData[nameof(Trip.EndDate)];

                vm.Trip.AccommodationPhone = TempData[nameof(Trip.AccommodationPhone)].ToString();
                vm.Trip.AccommodationEmail = TempData[nameof(Trip.AccommodationEmail)].ToString();

                context.Trips.Add(vm.Trip);
                context.SaveChanges();
                TempData["message"] = $"Trip to {vm.Trip.Destination} added";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My view

```
@model TripViewModel
@*
    
*@
@{
}
<h4>Add Trip Destination and Dates</h4>
<form asp-action="Add" method="post">

    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Trip.Destination">Destination</label>
        <input asp-for="Trip.Destination" class="form-control">
        <hr />
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Trip.Accommodation">Accommodation</label>
        <input asp-for="Trip.Accommodation" class="form-control">
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Trip.StartDate">Start Date</label>
        <input asp-for="Trip.StartDate" class="form-control">
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Trip.EndDate">End Date</label>
        <input asp-for="Trip.EndDate" class="form-control">
        <hr />
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" asp-controller="Trip" asp-action="Add">Next</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary " asp-controller="Trip" asp-action="Cancel">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

My model

```
namespace Trip_Log.Models
{
    public class Trip
    {
        public int TripId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a destination")]
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a start date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an end date")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        

        public string Accommodation { get; set; }

        public string AccommodationPhone { get; set; }

        public string AccommodationEmail { get; set; }

        public string ThingToDo1 { get; set; }

        public string ThingToDo2 { get; set; }

        public string ThingToDo3 { get; set; }

        public string ThingsToDo { get { return ThingToDo1 + "\n" + ThingToDo2 + "\n" + ThingToDo3; } 
    }
}
```

TripViewModel

```
public class TripViewModel
    {
        // Used to shape multiple entities from one or more models into a single object
        // 
        public Trip Trip { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, seens like you posted the wrong model since in your controller you expected to receive TripViewModel and the model you showed is Trip.

Second, the validation goes to the top of the property, like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an end date")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: I added the trip view model and adjusted the validation. That doesn't solve my issue though

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace anchor tag with button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

And then make sure you load `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`,then when you click the button,form will be validated and go to action `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is because I was missing the hidden input field stating the page number.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="PageNumber" />
```

The next button is also needs to be like so, since as another user pointed out anchors use get.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Next</button>
```

Both the validation and redirects started working with these two changes applied to the View.